# How to configure AD to enable SharePoint users to authenticate with username@custom.com rather than domain\username?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

How can I configure Active Directory to enable SharePoint users to authenticate with username@custom.com rather than domain\username?

I have done this before and by adding an item to the select box found in '[username] Proeprties' > 'Account' > 'User login name' but I cannot remember how to do this.

Comment: This is a good question for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com but not for this site as it is not programming related.

Comment: Thanks skeletank, I have posted now posted it there. Should I delete this question? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53481/how-to-configure-ad-to-enable-sharepoint-users-to-authenticate-with-usernamecus

Comment: Yes, I would suggest deleting your question here.  It may not delete it initially but I think that an admin will come through and take care of it.